# Inno Setup installer on Windows XP gives "not a valid win32 application"

Tags: installation, inno-setup, windows-xp

At some point after some of the Inno Setup updates, any installer generated with it fails to run under Windows XP, giving the error:

> not a valid Win32 application

Is there any setting I can change in the setup script to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 6, Inno Setup no longer supports Windows XP.

See [Inno Setup 6 revision history](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.0-whatsnew.htm):

> - **OS requirements change:** Windows 2000, XP, and Server 2003 are no longer supported. Windows Vista is now the minimum supported operating system.

Comment: Thanks. I googled a bit until I found your answer, lots of random articles.